# Enable SP Site Collection feature in powershell for all sites

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

Hello I would like to run a script to enable a site collection feature on all sites within a web application. Here is my script:

```
Add-PSSnapin -name "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://sharepointtest/

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{

Enable-SPFeature -Identity Reporting -url $SPSite
}
```

I think I am not passing the url correctly as it gives this error:

[image]

Anyone know what I am doing wrong! Not the best with powershell by all means!

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a SPSite object and the Enable-SPFeature just needs the URL.  Just use the "URL" property of the SPSite object - `$SPSite.url`